# PC Crash With Artifacts

Tags: visual-artifacts

So 3 weeks ago my gtx560 died and i had to replace it. I bought gtx 750ti and everything seemed fine. but 1 week ago my pc started crashing 1-2 time a day while surfing on the internet or doing something else (no blue screen just weird sound and visual artifacts like this

[image].

After restart freeze and visual artifacts are gone but not forever.

I tried updating my drivers and cleaning gpu but still same.

I want to know is my gpu dead (dieing) ? thanks.

My card has warranty so i think i will be able to replace it. But first i want to know if my gpu has problem.

1 week ago i updated my drivers from GTA V game ready driver to newer one and after 2 days pc started crashing as i said. Then i switched it back to previous version as i thought that was a problem but no result crashing kept going. PC crashed 5 times so far 1 time in witcher 3 and 4 times while surfing on the internet or doing something on desktop. so i don't think GPU overheat is a problem here.

When first GPU gtx560 died i was not able to even run windows as i had artifacts all over BIOS. So i am wondering if something similar is going to happen this time.

PC Specs: 8 gb ram i7 2600k windows 8.1 x64 no idea about motherboard or power supply but i believe they are ok but mayebe i am wrong.

My gtx750ti is overclocked by default as its box has text gtx750ti OC.

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts on screen use to come from hardware issues, rather than software ones. Very often they correspond with **VRAM malfunctioning**.

Overheating could be the origin of the problem. Check it with [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads) (Extreme version is good for you, 30 day trial available) at `Computer --> Sensor` option.

In order to find a clear way to reproduce the error (if you want to send the card to technical service), try the **Stability Test** inside AIDA64 at `Tools --> Stability Test`.

Other possibilities:
- Some **burned chips or circuits** on the card (up or down, check both sides)
- **Cooler not contacting** OK with some VRAM chip. Remove, check thermal pads, and mount again.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/De6aCQ6.png Stressing GPU and CPU for 7 minutes temperatures were always below 60 and nothing suspicious happened like crashing or artifacts. Checked GPU and everything seems fine no damaged parts there.